# Levenshtein Distance of transitively similar words

Tags: python, performance, graph, edit-distance, trie

The code's purpose is this: Two words are friends if they have a Levenshtein distance of 1. That is, you can add, remove, or substitute exactly one letter in word X to create word Y. A word’s social network consists of all of its friends, plus all of their friends, and all of their friends’ friends, and so on. Count the friends in the social network of a certain word.

My code is implemented using the Trie written by Steve Hanov. His code is here: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114.

What I did was this:

```
social_links = set_up_dictionary_from_text('dictionary.txt')
tree = Trie()
for i in social_links:
    tree.insert(i)
def find(keyword):
    neighbors = [keyword]
    already_in_set = set()
    while len(neighbors) > 0:
        if neighbors[-1] not in already_in_set:
            temp = neighbors[-1]
            already_in_set.add(neighbors.pop())
            current_neighbors = search(tree, temp)
            neighbors.extend(current_neighbors)
        else:
            already_in_set.add(neighbors.pop())
    return(len(already_in_set))
```

This code works, but runs over 8 minutes for files that are over 100,000 words. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or should I not use Python for this?

Comment: Two suggestions: when traversing the friends closure for one node, cache/record which nodes are friends along the way. And remember the friend relation is symmetric: `friend(x,y) == friend(y,x)`

Comment: It's hard to review this code because we can't run it. We need the code for the functions `set_up_dictionary_from_text` and `search`. Note that `search` must be different from the function with that name in Steve Hanov's code, because his function has the signature `search(word, maxCost)` but yours seems to be `search(trie, word)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a Python issue. Rather this is an issue of the implementation itself.

I agree with @Gareth Rees . You should always provide a minimally working example of the code. This is true for StackOverflow and especially true for CodeReview. In that respect all we can review is the little snipped you provide *under the assumption that the functions you don't provide do certain things*.

The first thing that you can cut is the `else:` block. It enters iff the last element of `neighbors` is in `already_in_set` and what it does is it adds the last element of `neighbors` to `already_in_set`; in other words: nothing. As a side effect you do pop the last element and since you do it in both cases it is better allocated above the `if`.

It looks like `search(tree, temp)` will return an iterable thing containing all rank 1 neighbors of `temp`. If you don't do any caching, `search` is incredibly slow! Loosely speaking that's `O(len(dictionary.txt) * max([len(word) for word in dictionary.txt])^2)` for the naive implementation and `O(max([len(word) for word in dictionary.txt]) * depth(tree))` for the one given in the blog post you mention.

To make matters worse, you do this for every friend of a word exactly one (since you prune duplicates). So what your running is `O(len(dictionary.txt)*max([friends(word) for word in dictionary.txt])*O(search))` which in the very crudest worst case can be `O(len(dictionary.txt)^4)` (**!**); although this case is only relevant for theoretical considerations.

Here is a list of things you can do:

- Cache the Levenshtein distance of two words; also you don't need the actual value, rather the result of the expression `distance <= 1` so there is room for more optimization. Also this is symmetric: `distance(a,b) = distance(b,a)` so you can cache two values for every computation
- Cache the result of `search(tree, temp)`. Again this is symmetric: `if b in search(tree,a) then a in search(tree,b)` so you can cache this result for every element of `search(tree,a)` without ever computing them [note that this is reflexive too: `a in search(tree,a)`]
- Cache the result of `find(keyword)`. `find` defines a group relation on `dictionary.txt`; hence if `b in find(a)` and `c in find(a)` then also: `a in find(b)`, `a in find(c)`, `c in find(b)`, `b in find(c)`. You can simply cache this number for every element in the network of a.

Doing all these things will reduce worst case performance to 
`O(O(find)+O(search)+O(distance)) = O(len(dictionary.txt)^2)` and should make it substantially faster. You could think of ways to reduce the number of computations needed for `search` and `distance` potentially reducing the overall complexity, but I didn't think into this further.